# Unknown class name PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, applepay

Xcode error screenshot:

[image]

Working environment: Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.0, Mac OS X 10.11.3

I was working on my own Table View Controller to interact with Apple Pay and I copied the sample code from Apple.

In my PaymentTableViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import PassKit
import Contacts

class PaymentTableViewController: UITableViewController, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
    ...
}
```

But then as it was auto-compiled into Objective-C to "Abletive(My project name)-Swift.h":

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Abletive26PaymentTableViewController")
@interface PaymentTableViewController : UITableViewController <PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate>
```

Now and as it should be correct

But it says **Unknown class name PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate** and **Unknown type name PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus** instead in the Abletive-Swift.h when I tried to compile and run, apparently this is happening because of Objective-C compatibility right? Because there is no error whatsoever in the Swift code.

My project is currently half Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: never show screenshots of code, show code as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your BridgingHeader.h file

```
#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>
```

If you encounter more errors in "YourProjectName-Swift.h" find frameworks in which are classes that causes error and add imports in BridgingHeader.h like

```
#import <FrameworkInWhichIsClass/FrameworkInWhichIsClass.h>
```

Comment: thanks alot! I actually added #import <PassKit/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.h> to make it correctly compiled